# WSO2 - API Manager - What is the difference between API version and API revision

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am reading the wso2 API manager's latest version 4.2.0. We have API version: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-versioning/create-a-new-api-version/#! and API revision: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/create-api/create-api-revisions/

What is the difference between the two? are the version for API code changes and the revision for API manager configuration related to a given API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API revision feature was introduced in the 4.x.x APIM series. The main difference between API version and API revision is that a new API version acts like a separate API, while an API revision is the same API with internal changes.

If we need to make changes such as modifying a mediation policy, adjusting security configurations, updating documentation, or simply changing the description of the API, it creates a separate revision that can be deployed on gateways. In an API revision, it is possible to restore back to the previous revisions if we want to revert the new changes.

Additionally, even if you want to test out a new runtime configuration, API revision provides the ability to test it on an independent Gateway before applying the same change to all the Gateways.

Generally, you can use API version for major changes and API revisions for minor changes in the APIs.

Comment: So mainly api version is for code level changes and api manager is for api manager configuration changes?

Comment: Yes, that can be used in that way. It depends on your design. Even the API version can also be used for API manager configuration changes (you can change API manager configurations after creating the new version of the API).